# Vim plugin to connect between tag or block?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

[image]

Hello vimers !

As you see on the picture, there is a vertical line to connect between opening tag and closing tag(html) or on function data.

Is there a plugin in vim connect between tag or block program, like in modern text editor ???

Comment: What does "connect between tag" mean?  As you said there is vertical line that connects them already.

Comment: the picture above using visual studio code

Comment: It doesn't have a vim plugin?  Are you asking about `vim` or `vi` in a Unix'ish like terminal?  If so you can use `%` to jump between code block delimiters like '{' and '}' and '(' and ')' and '[' and ']'.

Comment: these lines are called `indent lines` you should find what you need without a problem now. https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/666/how-to-add-indentation-guides-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the built-in help for `list` and `listchars`
This should do the trick:

```
:set listchars=tab:\|\
:set list
```

(notice, that there's a space after the last backslash)